# How to keep H1 only on homepage?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I know it can be done, but I tried some line of codes and didn't work for me.
This is my header:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_logo', '') != '') { ?>
            <h1 class="site-title logo"><a class="mylogo" rel="home" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><img relWidth="<?php echo intval(get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_maxWidth', 0)); ?>" relHeight="<?php echo intval(get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_maxHeight', 0)); ?>" id="ft_logo" src="<?php echo get_theme_mod(FT_scope::tool()->optionsName . '_logo', ''); ?>" alt="" /></a></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
            <h1 class="site-title logo"><a id="blogname" rel="home" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "keep H1 only on homepage." What output are you seeing, and what output do you expect?

Comment: The site tile (H1) is on every page. And in the article page I have two H1, one the site title, and the other the article title.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your custom css and replace ‘page1’ with your home page ID. You can use the same code and specify the class if you only want to apply to a certain H1 class type.

```
.h1{
display:none;
}
.page1 .h1{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the homepage ID?

Comment: See below. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-find-your-wordpress-page-id-and-post-id-and-what-you-can-do-with-them

Comment: I don't have a custom homepage, my homepage is from the latest articles and I can't find the ID for that.

Comment: Go to the page/post you are using as homepage and take the id number from the url as in the example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a page or post for the homepage, the theme makes my homepage from the latest articles.